# What are the limit points of $\{ (\frac mn,\frac 1n):m,n=1,2,... \}$

Tags: real-analysis

What are the limit points of the set $$\{ (\frac{m}{n},\frac 1n):m,n=1,2,... \}$$

that are not contained in the set?

My attempt:

Setting $$m:=kn, k=1,2,...$$

We have the element $(k,\frac 1n)$ is in the set, so for $(x_n)_{n>=1}=(k,\frac 1n)$ we obtain limit points that are not contained in the set which are $$(x,0)\text{ ,  }x=1,2,...$$

Also we have for $m=1, (\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$ is in the set so similarly $(0,0)$ is a limit point not contained in the set, so: $$(x,0), x=0,1,2,...$$ are all of the limit points not contained in the set.

Is this correct? I see a solution as I have questions and answers but the solution in the answer is:

$$(x,0),x>=0$$

Are the limit points of the set that are not contained in the set.

But this implies all non negative real values for $x $ and I can't seem to figure out why that would be the case. Appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the set in question $S$. Take some fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$. For each integer $q$, the interval $(x - \frac{1}{q}, x + \frac{1}{q})$ must contain some rational number of the form $p/q$ (though it's possible that $p/q = x$, or that the fraction $p/q$ is not in lowest terms). Then $(p/q, 1/q) \in S$, and the distance from $(p/q, 1/q)$ to $(x, 0)$ is at most $2/q$. This gives a sequence of points in $S$ converging to $(x, 0)$.

It's easy to show that no other limit points can exist. Drawing a diagram may help you convince yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to understand what you have said and it may take some time, just to clarify you are saying $(x,0) $ for real number $x $is a limit point not contained in $S$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.